# Equivalent of Ctrl + Shift + A of intelliJ in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-12

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> command in intelliJ lets me search for an action. Is there an equivalent command in Eclipse?

Comment: Have you seen `Quick Access` field?

Comment: No, I hadn't! That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Let's make it an appropriate answer then. ;)

Comment: this would be great if it was a list with other IDEs. Hard to search SO for "ctrl" "shift" and "a" equivalents...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Quick Access` field located somewhere in the upper right corner by default. You can also access `Quick Access` with the default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

By default there's only Ctrl + Shift + L which opens up the list of shortcuts.

There's a contextual menu that you can open with Ctrl + 1.